# Describing past, present and future in only one sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Let's say I have three maps that show the layout of a highschool in 1980, in the present and a proposed redevelopment for 2030. I want to use a single sentence to describe what I am seing. I have thought of the following, but I am not sure if the grammar is correct. Could someone help me?

"The maps illustrate the changes Newbury High School has and will undergo from 1980 up until 2030"

I want to know if the "has and will undergo" structure is grammatically correct.

Comment: is it though or thought

Comment: *...the  changes it **has undergone, is undergoing,** and **will undergo** from 1980 to 2030*. You need to inflect every instance of the ***main*** verb differently, as well as the auxiliary.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to combine "has undergone" and "will undergo" without using the main verb twice, but this doesn't work because the main verb is in a different form in each branch of the predicate.

Another problem with this approach is that you are predicting the future, a fruitless endeavor.  You don't actually know whether the plans reflected in the map will be realized.

I would just rewrite:

> The maps illustrate Newbury High School's changes and planned changes from 1980 to 2030.

Or

> The maps illustrate Newbury High School's actual and planned changes from 1980 to 2030.

Or

> The maps illustrate changes Newbury High School's campus has undergone since 1980 along with planned development through 2030.

Or something else along those lines.  If you are firm in your desire to use "undergo" in the passive voice for both past and future, it should be

> The maps illustrate the changes Newbury High School has undergone and will undergo from 1980 up until 2030.

Answer (score -1):

Using only the verb have and its forms

"The maps illustrate the changes Newbury High School has had from 1980 to the present and will have till 2030"

Answer (score -2):

I believe it should be "had" instead of "has" as the changes were made in the past.

> The maps illustrate the changes Newbury High School **had** and will undergo from 1980 up until 2030.

Comment: It's ***has undergone***, not ***had***.